# Split two delimited strings into arrays of words, merge, then remove duplicates

Tags: php, cpu-word, array-unique

I'm struggling to remove duplicates words found within two strings.

When I call `array_unique`, the duplicated words are not removed.

```
$a = 'mysql string 1';// basically words A, B, C
$b = 'mysql string 2';// basically words D, A, E
$a_b_array = array($a, $b);
sort($a_b_array);
$a_b_string = implode("\n", array_unique($a_b_array));

echo $a_b_string; //returns $a and $b with duplicated data
```

Expected result would be: A, B, C, D, E

Comment: Where's the closing parenthesis for `implode()`?

Comment: Your array only contains the two unique elements... maybe you are looking for an array of unique words... in that case the two strings need to be exploded by whitespace characters then merged together prior to the array unique call.

Comment: Edited, with result and typo ) fixed

Comment: Orangespill something like $a_string = explode("\n", $a); $b_string = explode("\n", $b); $a_b_array = array($a_string, $b_string);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you are dealing with an array of two elements. You will need to explode each element into arrays first.

```
<?php
// define your inputs    
$a = 'A, B, C';
$b = 'D, A, E';

// explode the string into arrays and merge them
$a_b_array = array_merge(explode(",", $a), explode(",", $b));

// trim off any pesky leading or trailing spaces from the elements
$a_b_array = array_map("trim", $a_b_array);

sort($a_b_array);
// tape the elements back together separated by a newline
$a_b_string = implode("\n", array_unique($a_b_array));
echo $a_b_string;
```

Comment: That did it. It needs the array_map "trim" to work, otherwise was still adding duplicates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 'mysql string 1'; // basically words A, B, C
$b = 'mysql string 2'; // basically words D, A, E

$a_explode = explode(" ", $a);
$b_explode = explode(" ", $b);

$a_b_array =  array_unique(array_merge($a_explode, $b_explode));
sort($a_b_array);
var_dump($a_b_array);
echo implode(", ", $a_b_array);
```

Output :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string 'mysql' (length=5)
  3 => string 'string' (length=6)
1, 2, mysql, string
```